# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I've got the following procedure to insert a user into a database. I use 4 in-parameters and 1 out-parameter. The out-parameter is filled with a sequence. 
The table structure is a user_id and the names of the 4 first parameters.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_user
(
P_USERNAME IN varchar2, 
P_PASSWORD IN varchar2, 
P_COMPANY_EMAIL IN varchar2,
P_EMPLOYEE_ID IN number,
P_USER_ID OUT int)
AS

BEGIN


 INSERT INTO system_users.users(USERNAME, PASSWORD, COMPANY_EMAIL, EMP_ID) 
 VALUES
 (P_USERNAME, P_PASSWORD, P_COMPANY_EMAIL, P_EMPLOYEE_ID);


 dbms_output.put_line (P_USER_ID);

END;
```

I get the error that I have the wrong number or types of arguments when I call the procedure. I called it like so:

```
insert_user('user', 'password', 'mail@mail.com', '5');
```

I have tried calling it with begin and end around it, I have tried the number without quotes, all wiithout quotes.

What am I doing wrong? Can it have something to do with the trigger not filling the user_id?

Regards,

Vincent

EDIT: JIC it is the trigger, here is the code for the trigger. It worked, but I saw a snag in the code so I edited it. FSR it says that the table I am trying to find (system_users.users) does not exist (invalid identfier)

PLEASE PLEASE help me!

```
create or replace trigger user_trig_bi
        Before insert on system_users.users
        for each row    

begin
            select user_seq.nextval
            into new.user_ID
            From dual
      where exists (SELECT emp_id 
                    from hrm_repo.employees 
                    where hrm_repo.employees.emp_id = system_users.users.emp_id);
END;
```

The error I get is:
Error(7,55): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SYSTEM_USERS"."USERS"."EMP_ID": invalid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your procedure has an `out` variable, provide it with a fifth variable to get the `out` value:

```
declare
  p_user_id int;
begin
  insert_user('user', 'password', 'mail@mail.com', '5', p_user_id);
end;
```

Note: You don't set the value in your procedure, so you could either let it away at all or you have to set it in your procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respond! It worked, or it would've worked if my trigger was correct.

Could you maybe help me out with the fault in my trigger to fill the p_user_id?

Comment: I will but can you still help me with my trigger? Thanks in advance! In the meantime I decided to cut out the part where I verify if the emp_id exists in the other table, and it says the new.user_id must be defined.

Comment: @VinnyHummel: I don't know about the trigger. It does say the table doesn't exist. Does it?

Comment: Yes, it says the table doesn't exist, but it does exist. I also executed all the grants on the table. I can even insert data into the table, yet the trigger tells me it's invalid.

Comment: @VinnyHummel: Trust me. It is never wrong. Do you have the same user connecting?